# How to connect two comboboxes in c# dynamically?

Tags: c#, mysql, dynamic, combobox, connection

I'm new in c# world, so i need your help to solve this problem.
i have a mysql database with 5 tables each has 3 columns.
In visual studio i have 2 comboboxes next to each other. The 1st CB is listing the table names.(this is OK)
In the 2nd CB i want to list the columns which belong the 1st combobox selected table.
When i choose 'A' table in 1st combobox the 2nd CB lists only 'A' table's columns. And when i choose 'B' table in 1st combobox the 2nd CB lists only 'B' table's columns.
For now i can make that when i choose 'A' table, 2nd CB lists the columns but when i choose 'B'table 2nd CB add 'B' table's columns to the list, and i see 6 column names instead of 3.
Can you help me????

Comment: If you put some code here people here could help better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you cleared the items of the 2nd Combo? You should clear the items before you do the new databind.

```
 ComboBox.Items.Clear();
```